# arcode scanning and identifying 3d objects like ARKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Does arcode have scanning and identifying 3d objects like ARKit?If not when is that feature expected?

Comment: ARCore on its own cannot identify 3D objects. You need something like Google Vision API / MLKit to do that. Best place to ask this would be [ARCore-SceneForm SDK on Github](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the discussion now about this: [Feature request : 3D Object Detection](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/418)

And you can Subscribe for notifications to know when this will be done